# C# Comparing lists of data from two separate databases using LINQ to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have 2 SQL Server databases, hosted on two different servers. I need to extract data from the first database. Which is going to be a list of integers. Then I need to compare this list against data in multiple tables in the second database. Depending on some conditions, I need to update or insert some records in the second database.

My solution: 
(WCF Service/Entity Framework using LINQ to Entities)

1. Get the list of integers from 1st db, takes less than a second gets 20,942 records
2. I use the list of integers to compare against table in the second db using the following query:

```
    List<int> pastDueAccts; //Assuming this is the list from Step#1
    var matchedAccts = from acct in context.AmAccounts
                       where pastDueAccts.Contains(acct.ARNumber)
                       select acct;
```

This above query is taking so long that it gives a timeout error. Even though the AmAccount table only has ~400 records.

1. After I get these matchedAccts, I need to update or insert records in a separate table in the second db.

Can someone help me, how I can do step#2 more efficiently? I think the Contains function makes it slow. I tried brute force too, by putting a foreach loop in which I extract one record at a time and do the comparison. Still takes too long and gives timeout error. The database server shows only 30% of the memory has been used.

Answer (score 0):

Profile the sql query being sent to the database by using SQL Profiler.  Capture the SQL statement sent to the database and run it in SSMS.  You should be able to capture the overhead imposed by Entity Framework at this point.  Can you paste the SQL Statement emitted in step #2 in your question?

Comment: The problem is when I run SQL Profiler, nothing appears in the trace as I debug through my code. All other queries above the line with "Contains" run fine and generate SQL queries in the Profiler trace.

Answer (score 0):

The query itself is going to have all 20,942 integers in it.

If your `AmAccount` table will always have a low number of records like that, you could just return the entire list of `ARNumber`s, compare them to the list, then be specific about which records to return:

```
List<int> pastDueAccts; //Assuming this is the list from Step#1
List<int> amAcctNumbers = from acct in context.AmAccounts
                          select acct.ARNumber

//Get a list of integers that are in both lists
var pastDueAmAcctNumbers = pastDueAccts.Intersect(amAcctNumbers);

var pastDueAmAccts = from acct in context.AmAccounts
                     where pastDueAmAcctNumbers.Contains(acct.ARNumber)
                     select acct;
```

You'll still have to worry about how many ids you are supplying to that query, and you might end up needing to retrieve them in batches.

**UPDATE**

Hopefully somebody has a better answer than this, but with so many records and doing this purely in EF, you could try batching it like I stated earlier:

```
//Suggest disabling auto detect changes
//Otherwise you will probably have some serious memory issues
//With 2MM+ records
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

List<int> pastDueAccts; //Assuming this is the list from Step#1

const int batchSize = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < pastDueAccts.Count; i += batchSize)
{
    var batch = pastDueAccts.GetRange(i, batchSize);

    var pastDueAmAccts = from acct in context.AmAccounts
                         where batch.Contains(acct.ARNumber)
                         select acct;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Chris. Unfortunately, right now in DEV environment AmAccount table has about 400 records, in production it will have 2 million records. This way if I pull 2 million records in memory I dont know how much for a performance hit would that be.

Do you think using a stored proc would be better?

Comment: 2 million... ouch! I've dealt with batching a few hundred thousand records with EF before, but my application hasn't been super performant (takes 5-15 minutes to complete read/write), but at least been easy to maintain, which is why that has been acceptable to me. Hopefully someone will chime in who is more versed in dealing with large data sets.